# Using intersect on more the two tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, ibm-midrange

I am trying to find the rows that all four tables share in common. 
I tried using this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 
INTERSECT
SELECT *
FROM TABLE2
INTERSECT
SELECT *
FROM TABLE3
 INTERSECT
SELECT *
FROM TABLE4;
```

But got no results, i know there are rows that meet this requirement. Because using union instead and adding "order by" i see four rows with the same description from different tables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `INNER JOIN` with conditions on the fields that you want
ex:

```
SELECT 
    t1.* 
FROM 
    TABLE1 t1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 t2
    ON t1.field1 = t2.field1
    AND t1.field2 = t2.field2
    ...
INNER JOIN TABLE2 t3
    ON t1.field1 = t3.field1
    AND t1.field2 = t3.field2
...
```

Comment: @Ferium but `INNER JOIN` will do the job

Comment: @Ferium why are you using `UNION` since you want an `INTERSECT` ?

Comment: Was about to, but found out your suggestion was right all along. Didnt know they used different name on the table and field for the same object. Thanks alot!

Comment: Thanks for help so far, but did not get the same results as i would expect from intersect. The results should list four of each object, one from each table. I got some objects from just one table. Guessing union is the wrong way to go.

Comment: my query:



SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT * FROM QGPL.UBRUKTCL
      UNION
      SELECT * FROM QGPL.UBRUKTYA
      UNION
      SELECT * FROM QGPL.UBRUKTFP
      UNION
      SELECT * FROM QGPL.UBRUKTPT
) AS TMP
ORDER BY
    odobnm;

Comment: @Ferium also can you post the desired output just to understand better what is the problem?

Comment: The result would be like this:

Field1    Field2
t1        unique program description
t2        unique program description
t3        unique program description
t4        unique program description

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32875/discussion-between-ferium-and-stephan)

Comment: what do you mean by unique? unique by the all 4 tables or by each table?